# Where does eclipse keep the information about the sources

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, projects-and-solutions

Yesterday I've imported some Java files within my Java project (just for being able to compile them into *.class files), I have then removed those files and now my Eclipse is constantly showing the following complaints:

```
Could not move: <the mentioned Java file>
  File not found: <again the mentioned Java file>
```

In top of that Eclipse mentions this issue being present in the plugin "org.eclipse.core.filesystem".

Now I'd like to do the following:
I'd like to go to the file which contains this obsolete reference and delete it in that file. (In Visual Studio this is a piece of cake)

How can I do this in Eclipse? Where does Eclipse store its project file(s)?

Comment: How did you import those files, drag-and-drop?

Comment: No, I used the context menu.

Comment: Paste should have the same effect... So not using the import menu

Comment: Have you checked your project in the filesystem? Cleaned the project in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Put the mouse cursor on the class or method name in source code and hit
Ctrl+Shift+G.